# python bs4 get element in popup without selenium

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to gather data behind a popup in this page. https://www.commonsense.org/education/game/garrys-mod

I am trying to gather data in the popup Subjects & skills.
I know I could use selenium, but I would rather not if it is not useful.

The data I am trying to gather is in there:

```
subjectSkills = gameSoup.find('div',class_='popper popper-popover subjects-skills')
```

However, it returns None, since it is behind a popup that looks like this:

```
<a href="#" id="subjects-skills" class="body-color" data-toggle="popover" data-content=".subjects-skills" data-arrow="false" target="_self">Subjects &amp; skills</a>
```

When the arrow button has been clicked, the value of `data-arrow` changes to true and this might be a solution, but I am unsure how/if it is possible to change this value.

Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output from there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for the popup from subjects I used

```
res = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "subjects-skills__item"})
```

and the return was is:

```
<div class="subjects-skills__item">
<h5 class="subjects-skills__label">Subjects</h5>
<ul>
<li>Science</li>
</ul>
</div>,
 <div class="subjects-skills__item">
<h5 class="subjects-skills__label">Skills</h5>
<ul>
<li>Creativity</li>
<li>Critical Thinking</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I got it by clicking the popup.. Highlighting the text, then right-click and go to inspect to locate the class.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests

def get_data():

    url = 'https://www.commonsense.org/education/game/garrys-mod'
    r = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36"})
    html_bytes = r.text
    soup = bs4(html_bytes, 'lxml')

    res = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "subjects-skills__item"})

    return res

test1 = get_data()
```

If you just want the text..

```
# For just the Text
for i in test1:
    print(i.text)
```

returns

```
Subjects
Science

Skills
Creativity
Critical Thinking
```